# Drupal : Request new Password email not going to all mail

Tags: drupal, passwords

I set up the email  for request new password here "admin/config/people/accounts". But Some of the email address receiving email some of the address not receiving mail.
I checked drupal log in "admin/reports/dblog" It says mail is going.

here is the php ini settings of smtp.

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp
  SMTP = localhost
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.smtp-port
  smtp_port = 25
```

Can anyone help ?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked in spam?

Comment: Yes i checked spam  @MyWay

Answer (score 0):

To emails send by SMTP, is indicated use [SMTP Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp).

After configured that module, try tests again.